# Number of HTML elements inside a Javascript string

Tags: javascript

I want to find the number `<li>`s present inside a JavaScript string.

For eg. if,

```
var lis = "`<ul><li><a href='http://sitename/profile/udhayakumar'>udhayakumar</a></li><li><a href='http://sitename/profile/lovely'>lovely</a></li></ul>`";
```

Then how to find the number of `<li>`s inside the `<ul>` tag. Is it possible to get this without inserting into any DOM element.

Comment: It is ofcourse possible without inserting in a DOM element, however that would be the cleanest way by far...

Comment: Why do you discard the best solution from the beginning?

Comment: Next time please mention explicitly which libraries are at your disposal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have jquery, you can do like this

```
$(lis).find('li').length
```

Comment: "Without jQuery you can try count <li> but no warranty for you get what you find" - jQuery is javascript.... ***fail*** - you can do all of this without that convoluted bloteware, much more performant, with much less overall code, with ***The exact same accuracy and warranty that you are finding the correct elements***

Comment: @rlemon Possible === true. Better performance === true. Write 6 times more code === true. I'll upvote your vanilla JS answer for taking the effort to write it though. `=]`(oh you deleted it?)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Esailija's was better and more on topic. I was more calling out the 'warranty' statement. Yes you *write* a bit more code, but you no longer have to *include* 9000 lines of overhead. If the toolkit is already being used then cool. However your last statement is still wrong.

Comment: @rlemon My last statement? Yeah it was assuming that the library is already included (otherwise the OP would have no reason to accept this answer I guess).

Comment: looking at the [op's history](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A698072+%5Bjavascript%5D), he explicitly mentions in many questions that he does not want jQuery answers. So this is probably a misclick.

Comment: "Without jQuery you can try count <li> but no warranty for you get what you find" - is the statement I was specifically commenting for. it is incorrect and leads people to think that these things are magically handled by 'jQuery' with some mystic voodoo we cannot as mortals achieve with vanilla js.

Comment: @rlemon I see, you meant OP's last statement. I agree completely, thanks for clearing that up. According to my research, jQuery is some kind of witchery combined with troll technology but not necessary for such a simple task.

Comment: HAHA @FabrícioMatté my bad mate, I didn't even notice I was not talking to the OP! Woops! I take it all back (from you, he is still wrong :P)

Comment: No problem rlemon. `:P` @Esailija, this seems to be the first question he didn't include that small "no libraries accepted" note, so who knows? I'll remove the flame-baiting line from this answer to cease the debate.

Comment: I just want to say you can use pure javascript to count the string '<li>' but not sure that was correct or not. I did not said jQuery is a GOD.... :(

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you mean by "possible without DOM element". If you mean possible without using the page's main dom tree (which is understandable), then yes.

As for using a separate disconnected tree, or just a disconnected subtree, then it's not understandable that you wouldn't want to do this.

```
var lis = "<ul><li><a href='http://example.org/profile/udhayakumar'>udhayakumar</a></li><li><a href='http://example.org/profile/lovely'>lovely</a></li></ul>";
var dom = document.implementation && document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("").body || document.createElement("body");
dom.innerHTML = lis;
alert(dom.getElementsByTagName("li").length);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HrcuF/

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions.  Note that unless you come up with an exceedingly complicated regexp, it will be hard to exclude edge cases (e.g. `<li>` tags inside a string in your html).  However, if you know enough about the type of input you expect, then you may be able to safely ignore cases like this.

#### 1. Count number of `<li>`'s:

```
var pattern = /.*?(<li>)/g;
var count = 0;
var result = pattern.exec(lis);
while(result != null) {
   count++;
   result = pattern.exec(lis);
}
```

Comment: Although it outputs the correct number in this case, it is just by coincidence. Have a look at the return value of `lis.match(/.*(<li>).*/)`.

Comment: Right you are... changed the regexp